# Setting the JOB_NAME column width for the LSF bjobs command

Tags: linux

Is there a way to tell the `bjobs` [LSF](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/technicalcomputing/platformcomputing/products/lsf/) command to use a wider column for `JOB_NAME`.  For example, instead of

```
JOBID      USER    STAT  QUEUE      FROM_HOST   EXEC_HOST   JOB_NAME   SUBMIT_TIME
12345678   MrFooz  RUN   some_queue src_box     exec_box1   *eat_job   Aug  20 08:40
```

I'd like to be able to see this

```
JOBID      USER    STAT  QUEUE      FROM_HOST   EXEC_HOST   JOB_NAME       SUBMIT_TIME
12345678   MrFooz  RUN   some_queue src_box     exec_box1   my_great_job   Aug  20 08:40
```

Comment: Try -w: -w Wide format. Displays job information without truncating fields.

Comment: @ThomasOliveira: is there a way to do something in between the default and `-w`?  For jobs without an explicit name, the whole command line is given, and I'd like to just be able to see more of it, not necessarily all of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-o` switch allows custom formatting of output (at least for LSF version 9.1.1.1).  From the man page:

```
     -o "field_name[:[-][output_width]] ...  [delimiter='character']"
            Sets the customized output format.


            *  Specify which bjobs fields (or aliases instead of the
               full field names), in which order, and with what
               width to display.


            *  Specify only the bjobs field name or alias to set its
               output to unlimited width and left justification.


            *  Specify the colon (:) without a w
```

I typically use:

```
bjobs -o "JOBID:10 SUBMIT_TIME:13 USER:5 STAT:5 QUEUE:6 EXEC_HOST:20 JOB_NAME"
```

So that output is:

```
JOBID      SUBMIT_TIME   USER  STAT  QUEUE  EXEC_HOST            JOB_NAME
12345678   Oct 30 08:34  me    RUN   long   4*machine1           really_long_jobname_can_go_on_forever
12345679   Oct 30 08:31  me    RUN   long   8*machine2           short_name
```